# SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list - error when migrating from Oracle to Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, distinct

I'm in the process of migrating our database from Oracle to Postgres. We have a number of hardcoded queries in our spring boot application that now break as result of this migration, and I'm having to fix them. One of them is the following:

```
String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE_A A " +
    "INNER JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.BIC = B.BIC " +
    "WHERE B.CUST_NUMBER=?" +
    "AND A.LOCATION=?" +
    "AND B.STATUS=?" +
    "AND B.LIVE=TRUE" +
    "ORDER BY A.TYPE, A.PARTY";
```

This query runs fine against oracle, but not against postgres. When running against postgres, I get the following error:
`SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

After doing some reading and even seeing similar questions about the same error, I am none the clearer on how I fix this for the above query. Removing the `DISTINCT` clause will fix the error, but obviously it is not the same query then, so that is a no go.

If anyone can offer some advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated, but: using `distinct` together with `*` and a join could indicate a code smell and can frequently be replace by using an EXIST condition provided you only need columns from one of the tables.

Comment: What is getting sent to the database?  Seems to me your are cramming things together without enough white space.  If I add whitespace and replace `?` with data, this works for me.

Comment: @jjanes: it depends on the Postgres version. The query works as-is with Postgres 13 or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query works in Postgres 13 and later. If you start a new project, then you should use the most recent version, rather than starting with a slightly outdated version

In older versions, you can wrap it in a derived table to get around that.

```
select *
from (
  SELECT DISTINCT * 
  FROM TABLE_A A 
    JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.BIC = B.BIC 
  WHERE B.CUST_NUMBER=?
    AND A.LOCATION=?
    AND B.STATUS=?
    AND B.LIVE=TRUE
) a
ORDER BY A.TYPE, A.PARTY
```

[Postgres 12 example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=694dfaed9216ddc7681021672e73fc3d)

[Postgres 14 example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=694dfaed9216ddc7681021672e73fc3d)

Comment: Thank you so much, you are right the solution was to update our Postgers instance from version 12 to 13 and this has resolved the issue! Is a change like this documented anywhere do you know? Just for future reference I would like to know how you would look to find the answer. Or did you simply just try it like you did on dbfiddle as a first guess?